# MATLAB: all fonts are blurry

Tags: matlab, fonts

All fonts within Matlab are very blurry -- GUI elements, command window, editor, etc.

[image]

I am running Matlab R2013b (8.2.0.701 64-bit maci64 August 13, 2013) under Mac OS X 10.9.1 with Java 7 (Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode).

What is causing the fonts to be rendered blurry and how do I resolve this?

Comment: is this happening in other softwares or just in MATLAB? Can you post a picture?

Comment: I added a screenshot to the post. The blurry font only occurs within Matlab, though I have not tested any other Java-based GUI apps.

Comment: This directly involves a tool primarily used for programming, hence I don't think it needs to be closed as off topic.

Comment: Someone found a solution (don't know whether it has cursor drawing issues mentioned by Dennis) https://discussions.apple.com/message/24435226#24435226

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that 2013b does not support retina displays, answer taken from [Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102946):

The reason for this behavior is because MATLAB R2013b does not currently take advantage of the full display capabilities on MacBook Pros with Retina displays. As a result, MATLAB R2013b will look less sharp than many other Mac applications, including earlier releases of MATLAB. At this point, there is no workaround beyond using an older release of MATLAB; we understand that this is a frustrating situation for impacted users. This webpage will be updated as new information becomes available.

Background Information:

R2013a and previous releases of MATLAB for Mac used Java that comes bundled with OS X; however, starting with MATLAB R2013b, MathWorks migrated to Oracle's Java 7 instead of the one bundled with OS X. This is to ensure the continued availability of MATLAB on Mac computers because Apple is in the process of deprecating its Java support.

R2013b is bundled with Java 7u11. This version lacks Retina display support as described in the following webpage.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8009754
A subsequent update with support for Retina displays, Java 7u40,was released in September 2013. Unfortunately, this update contain incomplete support for Retina displays—while visually attractive, the cursor insertion pointer is drawn at an incorrect location.

This behavior is described on the following webpage:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8020752
It is hard to know exactly where the cursor is, making editing text significantly more difficult.